# How to center dropdown based on size of parent

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown-component that when you click the button and dropdown is shown.
I want the triangle on the dropdown to always point to the center of the button that opened it regardless of how big it was.
Is this possible using css?

In the example below I am using a css-variable to achieve this. But in my real scenario I am unable to do this since the width of the container/button is decided by its contents.

Is it possible to reference the width of the container in any other way? I see that percentages used in left-positioning and the transform is based on the width of the menu it self. So that doesn't really help.

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem 50%;
  --button-size: 100px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
.button {
  position: relative;
  width: var(--button-size);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.button:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: red;
}

.item {
  white-space: pre;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.item + .item {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(calc(-75% - var(--button-size)/2));
}
.menu:after,
.menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.menu:before {
  border-bottom-color: black;
  top: -17px;
}

.menu:after {
  border-bottom-color: white;
  top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">Centered on me(but using css-variables)</div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would set the `:before` and `:after` pseudo `left` property to `50%`.

Comment: That only works if the popup menu has the same width as the button. If the button instead said "You should click this button to open the popupmenu" the menu would be too far to the left.

Comment: The problem is that I need to be able to reference the width of the parent(which is the same as the width of the button). Then I could do this on the menu: `left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(calc(-75% - var(--button-size)/2));`. But the width of the button should depend on its contents, so using a css-var is not possible

Comment: So if the menu itself is narrower than the button, you still want it left-aligned?

Comment: Yes. All that matters is that the top of the triangle should point to the center of the button.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a `margin: auto;` on the element that you want in the center could be useful as it automatically adjusts and places it's element in the center depending on the space available to it in any given situation.

Comment: Try editing my snippet and paste it into your answer. See if you can give me a working example. I don't really understand how to use the margin to fix my issue